# Винительный/родительный падеж при отрицании с наличием другого дополнения

Tags: грамматика, падежи, управление, дополнение, родительный-или-винительный

**Этот звук никогда не вызывал у человека поражение(ия) слуха.**

На Грамоте вот что нашёл:

"Когда нужен винительный падеж? Если при глаголе кроме данного существительного должно быть еще одно зависимое существительное или прилагательное: *он не считает книгу интересной; не прочитал статью за вечер; не обеспечили регион электроэнергией; Разве вы не считаете эту практику полезной?*"

Вроде как при глаголе "вызывает" есть ещё одно дополнение "у человека", выраженное существительным. Подходит под правило выше. Однако, в то время как варианты "он не считает книги интересной", "не прочитал статьи за вечер" явно не читаются, вариант моего примера с родительным падежом "не вызывает у человека поражения слуха" звучит приемлемо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Винительный падеж обозначает прямое воздействие на объект. А если действие отрицается, то и воздействия на предмет нет: вижу книгу (В.п.)  – не вижу книги (Р.п.). **Но так ли важно передавать эту семантику в речи и менять в связи с этим падежи?**

К примеру, почему надо говорить: он не читает книг. А что будет, если я скажу: он не читает книги. Наверное, появится **двусмысленность**: не читает книги, а что читает? Или что он там с ними делает? Такой ситуации  хотелось бы, конечно, избежать.

1) **Наличие у объекта дополнений и распространенных определений**

Чем менее конкретен предмет, тем чаще могут возникать такие вопросы. **Но если мы объект конкретизируем, то вполне сможем обойтись винительным падежом**, например: ***он не читает книги на такие темы*** или ***он не читает фантастику.***
Поэтому наличие  определений и дополнений позволяет нам использовать В.п.:

**Заданный пример:** Этот звук не вызывает у человека **поражение слуха**. (Но при усилении отрицания используется Р.п.)

Другие примеры: Несмотря на гибель героев, трагедия **не вызывает  чувство безысходности**. Человек должен принимать всегда такое положение, которое **не вызывает чувство дискомфорта и боли**, а, наоборот, облегчает боль.

2) **Наличие в предложении слова, по смыслу относящегося одновременно к прямому дополнению и к сказуемому**  [http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/66.htm#з_04](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/66.htm#%D0%B7_04)

***Он не считает книгу интересной.*** В этом случае  **отрицается не объект, а его признак**,  поэтому используется только В.п.

Comment: Подскажите, а каким членом предложения является это прилагательное "интересной"? Дополнением?

Comment: Это дуплексив, предикативное определение, оно имеет двойную связь: управление (глагол задает падеж) и согласование с существительным (подлежащим или дополнением) в  роде и числе.

Comment: А в примере: "Она не признает эту интриганку своей дочерью" — "своей дочерью" тоже дуплексив или всё-таки косвенное дополнение?

Comment: Я думаю, что здесь нет двунаправленных связей. Глагол управляет двумя дополнениями (кого и кем), каждое дополнение согласуется со своим местоимением. В учебнике рассматривается  дуплексивы с предложными формами вида "он заснул в костюме" (он в костюме и заснул в костюме),  "мы единодушны в своём порыве (мы в порыве и единодушны в порыве). Обычно эти формы имеют предлоги В и С. Очевидно,  по отношению к существительному (местоимению) они являются несогласованными определениями

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, в правиле, найденном Вами на Грамоте, нужно обратить внимание на слова "должно быть". Дополнение "у человека" можно убрать без потери смысла.

Здесь скорее действует другое правило: винительный падеж употребляется при совпадении различных, но одинаково звучащих падежных форм для устранения неясности: не читал сегодня газету (форма газеты могла бы обозначать множественное число). ([§201. Падеж дополнения при переходных глаголах с отрицанием](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/66.htm#%D0%B7_04))

**Этот звук никогда не вызывал у человека поражение слуха.**

А еще лучше:

**Этот звук никогда не вызывал у людей поражение слуха.**

Comment: Здесь слово поражение скорее неисчисляемое и выражает абстрактное явление, а не конкретный случай поражения слуха.

Comment: То есть напишем "не вызывал у людей поражения слуха", а в скобках напишем: "Не подумайте, что тут множественное число, так как  здесь слово *поражение* скорее неисчисляемое и выражает абстрактное явление, а не конкретный случай поражения слуха"?

Comment: Я вас понял. Кстати: "Ср. употребление с той же целью формы родительного падежа: Я не люблю проповедей (Горький); А вы разве газет не читаете? (Е. Мальцев)". Если использовать "проповеди" и "газеты", никаких проблем не возникает. Зачем ставить р.п.? Не спутаешь же их с формой родительного падежа единственного числа: "Я не люблю карандаша", "А вы разве журнала не читаете?" — так не говорят.