# Родительный падеж существительного, следующего за глаголом с отрицанием

Tags: грамотная-речь, управление

Отрицание действия, выраженного глаголом, указывает на необходимость постановки следующего за ним существительного в родительном падеже? Ниже приведена корректная форма?

**Не смотрел телевизора.**

Comment: Смотрите телевизор: он красивый!

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, посмотрите здесь:
[Винительный/родительный падеж при отрицании с наличием другого дополнения](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/439416)

Во-вторых, падеж выбирается в зависимости от вкладываемого смысла.
**Не смотрел телевизор** — обычно в конкретный момент, конкретную программу или передачу.

*Президент России Владимир Путин заявил, что **не смотрел телевизор**, когда транслировался матч между сборными России и Бельгии.*

**Не смотрел телевизора** — вообще этим не занимался.
*Отец Матфей не читал газет и **не смотрел телевизора**. Иногда ему являлся старец Лука и советовал, что нужно делать*. Петров, "Дочь генерала".

Хотя можно и обратные примеры найти. Короче, выбор — за автором, нарушений грамматики нет.

Comment: Почему не употребляют "Я не люблю карандаша" и "Вы разве журнала не читаете"?

Comment: Откуда я знаю? Это не мой текст. Конте5кста, наврное, нет подходящего. Хотя, если художник или искуствовед скажет такое, я не удивлюсь. Ну не любит он работать карандашом - или карандашных рисунков... Про журнал - в общем-то тоже. Ситуацию можно придумать, когда фраза не будет звучать странно.

Comment: Ваш ответ поддержал. Ещё пример: _Эти Листик и Буковка прославились тем, что очень любили читать книги. Они увлекались чтением до такой степени, что иногда даже не ходили в театр и кино, не слушали радио и **не смотрели телевизора**, а вместо этого сидели и читали какую-нибудь интересную книжку._  (Николай Носов. Незнайка в Солнечном городе.)

Answer (score 0):

*Не смотрел телевизора.* — неверно. || Стилистически плохо звучит.
*Не смотрел телевизор.* — верно.

Но возможно с другими глаголами, не настолько конкретными - *видел*:
*Не видел этого телевизора в магазине.*

Розенталь:
Родительный падеж, имеющий в рассматриваемой конструкции значение **подчеркнутого отрицания**, обычно употребляется при глаголах восприятия, мысли, желания, ожидания (видеть, слышать, понимать, думать, знать, хотеть, желать, ожидать и т.п.):
*Печали в ее словах Самгин не слышал (Горький);

Он... деревни не знал (Чехов);

Степка проглотил... конфеты и даже не заметил их вкуса (В. Гроссман).*

Comment: ― Мы в фильм ужасов играем, ― ответили они. Лагарпов **не смотрел фильмов ужасов**, но представлял, что это такое, ему рассказывали. Он забеспокоился. ― А как это? ― спросил он. [Алексей Слаповский. Жизнь Лагарпова (1999)]

Comment: Кальтлуфт любил работать, жалел тратить зря время, он не заходил после ужина в клубные помещения, не играл в карты и **не смотрел кинофильмов**  [Василий Гроссман. Жизнь и судьба, часть 2 (1960)]

Comment: @behemothus С фильмами канает, но с телевизором - никак.

Comment: Я больше семи лет не видел детей, не смотрел телевизора и не ел настоящей жареной картошки по-украински, на сале с луком и шкварками Яков Капустин - 2017

Comment: Он знал, что пресса его не жалует, хотя несколько месяцев не смотрел телевизора, один из надзирателей показал ему статью в «Ньюсуик». Тилли Бэгшоу - 2018

Comment: Он не подходил к телефону, не смотрел телевизора, не слушал радио, не принимал гостей, но однажды забылся и все же поднял телефонную трубку. Геннадий Прашкевич - 2015

Comment: @behemothus Ну и что. Полно книг нарушают стилистические нормы. Это плохо звучит. Получается, чтобы нарушения норм стали приемлемыми, нужно просто издать книгу?

Comment: Не надо вот только про нарушения норм. Вас никто не уполномочивал их определять.